# Rails 5 nested attributes alternative way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating an app that it needs to be customizable.

Ej: 
I have:

1. **Position scaffold**
2. Category scaffold
3. Class scaffold
4. Type Scaffold

Now, the situation is, **position table** *along other attributes*, includes a category attr, a class attr and a type attr. The problem I have is that every category, class and type is created and owned by another controller and moedel.

Now, here is where my problem comes to life.
when I tried to create a position *(even though I can actually see all categories, classes and types listed on my position view via **form.select**)* I cannot save a position with a category, class nor type.

I tried nested_attributes and don't work quite good in this situation.

**What is the appropriate method tho attack this from scratch base on my scaffolds?**

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to accept nested attributes. Anyway, share some code for models, controllers and views so we can find the errors instead of writing a whole solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tough to figure out what you need without seeing your code, but I'll try my best to help.

Keep in mind that Class and Type are reserved words in rails; Columns named _type are used for polymorphic relationships. And Class is used well for ruby classes. So as a general rule of thumb I would stay clear of those terms.

For you Position model:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :categories
  has_many :types
  has_many :classes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, :types, :classes
end
```

Then for your other models:

```
class NameOfClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :position
end
```

You also need to make sure that you add these nested attributes to the whitelist on you controllers. It should include any columns that you want to accept that will update other models. Keep in mind that this has to be the last thing listed.

In your Position Controller

```
PositionsController < ApplicationController

private

def position_params
  params.require(:position).permit(:id, :position_column_a, :another_column,
    categories_attributes: [:id, :position_id, :any_other_column_you_want],
    types_attributes: [:id, :position_id, :again_any_other_column])
```

Again, before you do anything I would look into renaming your scaffolds. the best way is to delete them and then regenerate. This will do the trick:

```
rails d scaffold Type
```

If you just need a simple dropdown of a list of categories you can try enums. However, it is not good for options that need to be customizable for the user. I typically only used them for statuses.

https://bendyworks.com/blog/rails-enum-sharp-knife

You can also read the API docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The model you suggest is not what the OP described. He said the position has a class, category and type. So it's a belongs_to and not has_many situation.

Comment: Pablo, I agree. I think he may have scaffolded everything without understanding how to properly use a class, category, and type. I recommended that he rename's his scaffolds and I'm sure there are better solutions if he shares some code.

Comment: Lazy Cougar if you could provide more details or let me know if my solution helped you out that would be great. I'm new to stack overflow so I don't have a high enough reputation yet to directly comment on your original post. I've been in your shoes before I'm more than happy to help you out.